# Inversion of Control, Dependency Injection and Strategy Pattern with examples in java

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, strategy-pattern

I am often confused by these three terms. These three look similar to me. Can someone please explain them to me clearly, with examples.

I have seen similar posts and don't understand completely.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Dependency Injection** refers to the pattern of telling a class what its dependencies will be, rather than requiring the class to know where to find all of its dependencies.

So, for example, you go from this:

```
public class UserFetcher {
   private final DbConnection conn = 
      new DbConnection("10.167.1.25", "username", "password");

   public List<User> getUsers() {
      return conn.fetch(...);
   }
}
```

to something like this:

```
public class UserFetcher {
   private final DbConnection conn;

   public UserFetcher(DbConnection conn) { 
      this.conn = conn;
   }

   public List<User> getUsers() {
      return conn.fetch(...);
   }
}
```

This reduces coupling in the code, which is especially useful if you want to unit test `UserFetcher`.  Now, instead of `UserFetcher` *always* running against a database found at `10.167.1.25`, you can pass in a `DbConnection` to a test database. Or, even more useful in a fast test, you  can pass in an implementation or subclass of `DbConnection` that doesn't even connect to a database, it just discards the requests!

However, this sort of primitive dependency injection makes *wiring* (providing an object with its dependencies) more difficult, because you've replaced accessing the dependency using a global variable (or a locally instantiated object) with passing the dependency around through the whole object graph.

Think of a case where `UserFetcher` is a dependency of `AccountManager`, which is a dependency of `AdminConsole`.  Then `AdminConsole` needs to pass the `DbConnection` instance to `AccountManager`, and `AccountManager` needs to pass it to `UserFetcher`...*even if neither `AdminConsole` nor `AccountManager` need to use the `DbConnection` directly!*

An **inversion of control** container (Spring, Guice, etc) aims to make dependency injection *easier* by automatically wiring (providing) the dependencies.  To do this, you tell your IoC container *once* how to provide an object (in Spring, this is called a *bean*) and whenever another object asks for that dependency, it will be provided by the container.

So our last example might look like this with Guice, if we used constructor injection:

```
public class UserFetcher {
   private final DbConnection conn;

   @Inject //or @Autowired for Spring
   public UserFetcher(DbConnection conn) { 
      this.conn = conn;
   }

   public List<User> getUsers() {
      return conn.fetch(...);
   }
}
```

And we have to configure the IoC container.  In Guice this is done via an implementation of `Module`; in Spring you configure an *application context*, often through XML.

```
public class MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {    
    @Override
    public void configure() {
       bind(DbConnection.class).toInstance(
           new DbConnection("localhost", "username", "password"));
    }
}
```

Now when `UserFetcher` is constructed by Guice or Spring, the `DbConnection` is automatically provided.

Guice has [a really good Wiki article](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation) on the motivation behind dependency injection, and further using an IoC container.  It's worth reading all the way through.

The **strategy pattern** is just a special case of dependency injection, where you inject *logic* instead of an *object* (even though in Java, the logic will be encapsulated in an object).  It's a way of decoupling independent business logic.

For example, you might have code like this:

```
public Currency computeTotal(List<Product> products) {
   Currency beforeTax = computeBeforeTax(products);
   Currency afterTax = beforeTax.times(1.10);
}
```

But what if you wanted to extend this code to a new jurisdiction, with a different sales tax scheme?  You could inject the logic to compute the tax, like this:

```
public interface TaxScheme {
    public Currency applyTax(Currency beforeTax);
}

public class TenPercentTax implements TaxScheme {
    public Currency applyTax(Currency beforeTax) {
        return beforeTax.times(1.10);
    }
} 

public Currency computeTotal(List<Product> products, TaxScheme taxScheme) {
    Currency beforeTax = computeBeforeTax(products);
    Currency afterTax = taxScheme.applyTax(beforeTax);
    return afterTax;
}
```

Comment: I looked for this explanation in several technical literatures but never found anything so didactic and complete as this. Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

Inversion of control means that a runtime framework wires all components together (for example Spring). Dependency injection is a form of IoC (I don't know if another form of IoC exists) (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Strategy pattern is a design pattern (defined by the GoF) where the algorithm can be replaced by another (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This is archived by provided several implementation of a same interface. When using an IoC like Spring, if you have several implementations of an interface, and if you can switch from an implementation to another by configuration, you are using the strategy pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend reading the introduction chapter of Spring's documentation, which focuses on this issue:  [Introduction to Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html)
The first few paragraphs should do.

And this also links to: [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)
Which also provides a motivational view of these very important core concepts.